# Clang format unwanted indentation

Tags: c, clang-format

I'm automating enforcing coding style using clang-format. Everything formats correctly, except for one unwanted artifact. The reduced version of my .clang-format config file is:

```
ColumnLimit: 120
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
IndentWidth: 4
Standard: Auto
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: ForIndentation
```

The code in question after formatting is:

```
static struct option long_options[] = { { "str1", no_argument, NULL, 'h' },
                                            { "str2", no_argument, NULL, 'v' },
                                            { "str3", required_argument, NULL, 's' },
                                            { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 } };
```

It is hard to display on Stackoverflow, but this is how it displays using 8 column tabs. All whitespace is spaces, except for the first character, which is a tab(but displays here as 8 spaces). So:

```
static struct option long_options[] = { { "str1", no_argument, NULL, 'h' },
<__tab_>                                    { "str2", no_argument, NULL, 'v' },
<__tab_>                                    { "str3", required_argument, NULL, 's' },
<__tab_>                                    { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 } };
```

This is not the formatting I'm looking for. Displaying with 4 column tabs gives the output I expect:

```
static struct option long_options[] = { { "str1", no_argument, NULL, 'h' },
<tb>                                    { "str2", no_argument, NULL, 'v' },
<tb>                                    { "str3", required_argument, NULL, 's' },
<tb>                                    { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 } };
```

However, I feel like there should not be a tab at all, and the alignment should be done by spaces alone, preventing the whole display tab size problem.

How can I setup clang-format to solve this?

Comment: `IndentWidth:4` and `TabWidth:4` leading to exactly one tab at the beginning is what I would expect.

Comment: If you do not want tabs, you have to specify `UseTab: Never`

Comment: Change `UseTab: ForIndentation` to `UseTab: Never`

Comment: To clarify: I actually want tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment. In my eyes this piece of code should contain no indentation, only alignment. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @AartStuurman Yes, since the struct initialization spreads over multiple lines, all lines but the first one are to be indented.

Comment: @Ctx Okay that makes sense. But why are all the spaces present after the indentation? I presume to make the indentation 'start' from somewhere around the '=' symbol? 4 column tabs does not look like clear indentation to me(more like alignment), while 8 column tabs does.

Comment: @AartStuurman The first tab is for regular code indention, the following spaces are another kind of indention to make it look "nicer". And remember: How the tabs are displayed depends on _your editor_, not on clang. You _tell_ clang, that your editor will display it with 4 columns. When it indeed displays a tab as 8 colums, set TabWidth and IndentWidth to 8

Comment: I understand that. My team uses different tab size settings, so I'm trying to find a good middleground. I think in this case the best option is to put the complete rvalue on the next line(not keeping the first line on there), in case it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Ctx Okay sorry for asking this again, but do you by chance know if there is a setting for that? In the docs I see nothing on breaking after assignment.

Comment: @AartStuurman I have already looked the options through, but at first glance I couldn't find something in this regard.

Comment: @AartStuurman "_My team uses different tab size settings_" if that's the case, the NO formatting involving TABs is going to work. If you tell `clang-format` that TABs will take up 4 spaces, but for _some_ people they take up 8 spaces, it will look wrong. Similarly telling clang TABs occupy 8 spaces when for some people it's 4 will look wrong. _Either_ get everyone to use the same tab-size setting _or_ to not use TABs in formatted source.

Comment: @TripeHound This is only a problem in this specific formatting case. If you use tabs for just indentation, and space for alignment, there is no issue when people use different tab size(allowing them to choose themselves how much indentation is good for their eyes). The problem with the current case is that we call the continuation 'indentation', while I want to achieve alignment at the same time. This is impossible with tab indentation. Either continuation indentation should be done with spaces, or the text to indent to should also be on it's own line, so it uses the same tab indentation.

Comment: @AartStuurman What happens if you have `static struct option long_options[] = {` and the corresponding `};` on separate lines?  The horizontal _positions_ of the four option lines in between might be different for different users, but they should, I'm guessing, be the same for all four lines. (And in passing, it's presumably being inside the `long_options[] = { ... };` block that makes clang treat those lines as being indented, not simply aligned).

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use `Cpp11BracedListStyle: true` and `UseTab: ForIndentation`. This slightly changes to the look of braced lists, but forces the use of spaces when aligning them.